# Lib folder is missing when creating java project in Eclipse Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)

Tags: java, eclipse, lib

[image: Java Project folder]I create a new java project in Eclipse (Eclipse 4.6.2)  In the root project directory I only have 3 sub-folders, .setting, src, and bin. The lib folder is missing

Comment: Eclipse doesn't create a lib folder for a new Java project.

Comment: Thank you greg-449. You are right Eclipse doesn't create a lib folder for a new Java project. We have to create the lib folder manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't create a lib folder for a new Java project base on greg-449's comment